# Scraping a http link using python beautifulsoup

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying scrape an http link from a site using regex and so far I have tried this.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request
import re
import csv
import time
import string
import sys
import requests
import json
user_agent1 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
url = "https://somesite.com"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent1,}
request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
page_html = data
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
data1  = page_soup.find_all("script")[5].string
```

in this code if i print(data1) its gonna give this output

```
                var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
            playerInstance.setup({
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                controls: true,
                flashplayer: "http://p.jwpcdn.com/player
/v/7.3.6/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                aspectratio: "16:9",
                fullscreen: "true",
                primary: 'html5',
                displaytitle: true,
                "preload": "auto",
                autostart: false,
                sources: [{"file":"https://archive.org/v.mp4","label":"1080p","type":"video/mp4
"}]
            });
```

in this output from variable data1 I am trying scrape http link

```
https://archive.org/v.mp4
```

so I added few lines of more code:

```
p = re.compile('file :(.*?);')
m = p.match(data1)
print(m)
```

but when I tried to `print(m)` it gives output `None`. How can I scrape http link into a variable?

I believe that I am making mistake in regex expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
import re
a = """var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
            playerInstance.setup({
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                controls: true,
                flashplayer: "http://p.jwpcdn.com/player
/v/7.3.6/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                aspectratio: "16:9",
                fullscreen: "true",
                primary: 'html5',
                displaytitle: true,
                "preload": "auto",
                autostart: false,
                sources: [{"file":"https://archive.org/v.mp4","label":"1080p","type":"video/mp4
"}]
            });"""

src = a.split("sources:")[1]
print re.search('(?P<url>https?://[^\s]([^"]*))', src).group("url")
```

**Output:**

```
https://archive.org/v.mp4
```

Comment: can you also show me how i can scrape http and https both of http type links in this regex expression